# CSS style dependency using many plugin

Tags: css

I'm using a plugin that use jQuery-ui and another one is using bootstrap. Because the plugin of bootstrap have many classes that are the same with jQuery-ui, they clashed. I know I can restyle them but that's a lot of work. Any better way to resolve that issue?

Comment: You can use Jquery-ui .js files and don't use .css file...

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery UI theme roller and on the last pages there is a input field for theme scope, which lets you make the CSS classes require a prefix.

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

If I set the scope input to ".mycustomscope", the generated jQuery UI CSS will have classes such as `.mycustomscope .ui-widget` and as far as I know, the plugins will utilize them as well.